# Qt .qrc reading in MSVC2017 vs MinGW 32

Tags: qt, qt5

I was trying to add an image to one of my labels in Qt 5.10.1. using the following code:

```
QPixmap* dndImg = new QPixmap(":/dnd.png");
ui->image->setMinimumSize(1, 1);
ui->image->setPixmap(dndImg->scaled(500,500, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
delete dndImg;
```

It's working fine when I use MinGW 32 but the image doesn't load when I use MSVC2017. I don't get any error but `dndImg->isNull()` returns `1`.

I have precompiled files provided by Qt, also I have visual studio 2017 ultimate with Visual C++ 2017.

I am not sure why is it working with MinGW and not with MSVC2017. Anyone else has the same problem?

Comment: Ensure rcc has compiled the .qrc file. Clean the build directory and rebuild all. If this doesn't help, can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: may be dump question - ru using qmake or cmake as project generator?

Comment: @SergioMonteleone I did that but still I don't see the image, but deleting the `build-*` folder worked. It's just silly how it can't compile changes in qrc file.

Comment: @ĽubomírCarik On qmake.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason, when using MSVC2017, the qrc file does not recompile. The only way I got to get this working is to delete the `build-*` folder and recompile the whole project.